# MySql can not grant privileges to root

Tags: mysql, root, privileges, sql-grant

I ran command `grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'root';`

And it keep showing following error

> 11:43:51  grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by
>   'root'    Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using
>   password: YES)    0.00045 sec

I also checked User table on Mysql it looks like below.

```
'%', 'root', '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '', ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', 'mysql_native_password', '', 'N'
'localhost', 'root', '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', 'N'
```

I do not know what is wrong with this? :<

How can I fix this without re-install MySQL. (Since, it worked well before what happened today)

Thanks for your answer :b

====================== Edit =================

Some of history, but I am not sure this will be useful or not.

Before I did this.

I import a dump. When I trying to access, some of procedures could not execute since, definer is different. So I did like this.

1. made a new schema and re-import the dump
2. create a user in mysql database and `flush privileges;`

And now I want to give privileges to new user. At first, I was trying with workbench(GUI of MySQL Client).

But when I trying to give privileges, it show error 1044, which I am facing now.

Now what can I do to fix this?

Comment: That is weird, as far as I know, root have access to everything. It is not also recommended to grant root access to all host.

Comment: @Vhortex Thanks for advise about root account.

Comment: Yes, by default root already has all privileges on all databases. You typically want to create a new user for database access. Also, your "identified by 'root'" should be "identified by 'password'".

Comment: @kojow7 my root account ID is 'root' and password is also 'root'. I will edit post some.

Comment: That's not a very secure password to use for your root account. Also just to clarify, the root user of your operating system is different from the root user on MySQL...you probably know that already, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @kojow7 yeah, thanks. I will remember that :D. I can see privileges with `show grants 'root'@'localhost';` and the result shows `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION`. It supposed to be work, right?

Comment: Why would you need to run that? it should have those privileges by default..I think we are not sure what your real issue is here..

Comment: Are you trying to allow the root user to have remote access to your dbms? Depending what you are doing, it is usually better to create a different user for this.

Comment: You have full access LOCALLY `'localhost', 'root', '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', 'N'`  You don't have ANY permission REMOTELY `'%', 'root', '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', '', ?, ?, ?, '0', '0', '0', '0', 'mysql_native_password', '', 'N'`

Comment: UPDATE *N* to *Y* and make sure that your "my" configuration file (Linux = my.cnf, Windows = my.ini) you set `bind-address = YOUR-PRIVATE-IP`

Comment: @LeaTano yeah. I got that. Thanks b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Access denied for root@%` suggests you are trying to login as root remotely and grant yourself these privileges. You will need to log in from localhost and perform this operation for it to be successful.

It should be pointed out that allowing unrestricted root access from remote hosts is very rarely a good idea.